# Integrating an Xcode/Swift App into an Wordpress database and user base

Tags: wordpress, xcode, swift4

I have a Wordpress site that is a user registration site with restricted content. I am attempting to build a native iOS App (Android next) that will refer to the users that have already signed up on the website, but also allow the registration of new users through the App.

I am a competent web developer but NOT overly familiar with Swift 4 (did some iOS stuff a few years ago but always standalone, not WP integrated). I have found a few tutorials on how to do this but they are all pre Swift 3, so fail to compile due to a number of errors:

- '()' is not convertible to 'Bool'
- Expected expression after operator
- Unary operator cannot be separated from its operand
- Missing argument label 'userMessage:' in call
- Alert' has been renamed to 'alert'
- Unterminated string literal

These errors stop the app compiling and from what I can ascertain it's because of the code being relevant to an older version of Swift (I am of course happy to be corrected on this).

The ViewController code is as follows:

```
//
//  RegisterPageViewController.swift
//  v2.0.2
//


import UIKit

class RegisterPageViewController: UIViewController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

@IBOutlet weak var userFullNameTextField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var userEmailTextField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var userMobileNumberField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var userPasswordTextField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var repeatPasswordTextField: UITextField!


override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


@IBAction func registerButtonTapped(_ sender: Any) {

    let userName = userFullNameTextField.text;
    let userEmail = userEmailTextField.text;
    let userMobile = userMobileNumberField.text;
    let userPassword = userPasswordTextField.text;
    let userRepeatPassword = repeatPasswordTextField.text;

    // Check for empty fields
    if(userEmail?.isEmpty ?? ||userPassword?.isEmpty ?? ||  userRepeatPassword?.isEmpty ??)
    {

        //Display alert message

        displayMyAlertMessage("All fields are required");

        return;

    }

    //Check if passwords match
    if(userPassword != userRepeatPassword)
    {
        //Display an alert message

        displayMyAlertMessage("Passwords do not match");

        return;

    }

    // Store data

    // Display alert message with confirmation

}

func displayMyAlertMessage(userMessage:String)
{

    var myAlert = UIAlertController(title:"Alert", message: userMessage, preferredStyle:
        UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert);

    let okAction = UIAlertAction(title:"OK', style:UIalertActionStyle.Default, handler:nil);

    myAlert.addAction(okAction);

        self.presentViewController(myAlert, animated:true,     completion:nil)

}



}
```

I'd like to be able to 'fix' this code if possible, or alternatively if you could direct to any other suitable solution that will allow me to connect the user registration and signup process to the Wordpress database that would be amazing!

Comment: Have you googled/researched each error and looked at the line where the error occurs? `"OK'` -> `”OK”`, cause string literals can only be delimited by `”`. Renames do sometimes have usable quickfixes. `userEmail?.isEmpty ?? ||` -> `userEmail?.isEmpty ?? false || ` cause optional bools can’t be chained together with `||` so iif userEmail is nil its probably empty too, or can assume its never nil and use `userEmail!.isEmpty` Or a `guard let userEmail = userEmail` or things like that.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Yes, I have looked individually. I've got rid of some of the errors already but I'll give your suggestion(s) a go and let you know. Thanks again ;-)